# How to pass a value from Jquery to angular Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have working to pass a value from Jquery to angular js. But I have found undefined in angular js.
My code :

```
HTML :
<button onclick="change('5')"></button>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="data" id="one" />

<button ng-click="test(data)">Test</button>

JQuery:
function change(data)
{
  $("#one").val(data).change();
}

Angular Js :

$scope.test= function(data)
{
   console.log(data)
}
```

But I got undefined. How can I do this ?

Comment: use `ng-click` like, `<button ng-click="change('5')"></button>`

Comment: actually jquery lite is already built in angular... So try doing everything angular way if you are using angular

Answer (score 2):

You can do it for sure*, however you *should* probably not, as this blend of jQuery and Angular will soon become hard to maintain. This is not really well-design.

Instead, use angular directives and methods, in your case it's straightforward:

```
<button ng-click="change('5')"></button>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="data" id="one" />

<button ng-click="test(data)">Test</button>
```

and in Angular controller:

```
$scope.change = function(x) {
    $scope.data = x;
};
```

---

<sup>* If you really want it: you need to let Angular know that you have changed the model from outside of digest cycle with manual `$("#one").val(data).change(); angular.element($("#one")).scope().$apply();`.</sup>

Comment: Where I will use angular.element($("#one")).scope().$apply(); ? In Jquery or Angular Js